# How to set dynamic marks parameter in pytest.param when using pytest_generate_tests()

Tags: python, pytest

I have a pytest setup where all of my tests are parameterized through data stored in a YAML file. Included in that YAML file are custom markers for various test instances.  I stripped out most of the code for simplicity.  The problem is the variable marker below needs to be of type _pytest.mark.structures.MarkDecorator

I can't seem to change the object type from string.  I'm thinking there must be a simpler/different way for what I'm trying to do but I'm just not seeing it...

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):

    ######################################################################
    # A bunch of code removed for simplicity but cm is defined in yaml file
    ######################################################################
    cm = "custom_marker"
    marker = f"pytest.mark.{cm}"
    final_str = pytest.param((1,2), marks=marker)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I wrote a library called [`parametrize_from_file`](https://parametrize-from-file.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the exact purpose parametrizing tests (in pytest) from YAML/TOML/JSON/NT files.  It supports custom marks, and might be a lot easier than writing your own parametrization code.

Comment: Thank you Kale.  Actually, you did answer my question.  You did pretty much exactly what I was looking to do. If I would have known about your plugin, I would have went that route instead.  Anyhow, I looked at your source code and how you dynamically handled markers and it showed me what I was doing wrong.  I'll post answer in "Answer Your Question" so I can format it better.

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer based on Kale's response.  Thank you Kale
I needed to change this:

```
cm = "custom_marker"
    marker = f"pytest.mark.{cm}"
    final_str = pytest.param((1,2), marks=marker)
```

to this:

```
cm = "custom_marker"
    marker = getattr(pytest.mark, cm)
    final_str = pytest.param((1,2), marks=marker)
```